# One table in my SQL Server 2008 Express r2 database is timing out

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been using a SQL Server 2008 Express R2 database for a few months now. Recently, one of my tables started timing out if I try to make an `UPDATE` through code or through Management Studio. I have tried making changes via the designer in management studio as well, and the same thing.

What can cause a single table to time out like this? My other tables are instant response to my changes, but this one just refuses to let me make any changes.

Comment: Are there any update triggers? Do you allow cascading triggers?

Comment: My C# code is listening to service broker events. But it is listening to all of the tables, and the one that I am having trouble with is changed the least often. One of my stable tables is updated multiple times a second

Comment: An UPDATE made through Management Studio shouldn't time out, what error message do you get? How long does it run before the error?

Comment: I just said it exceeded its timeout. I found the following error in the logs:
'
The query notification dialog on conversation handle '{40E56944-6911-E111-9B98-782BCB338E7E}.' closed due to the following error: '<?xml version="1.0"?><Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-8490</Code><Description>Cannot find the remote service &apos;SqlQueryNotificationService-738bcb49-6877-4b71-aac0-199411ad396b&apos; because it does not exist.</Description></Error>'.'

Comment: While I was unable to determine what was wrong with the table, doing a full restore of the database cleared the problem. I am going to open a new question on a bigger issue in which the database needs to restore almost every system restart (and fails at restoring)

Comment: Recursive triggers is NOT enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your bad table has some kind of trigger attached to it. I suggest firing up SQL Profiler to see exactly what queries are being sent to the table.